# mysqli_fetch_assoc() not returning anything

Tags: php, mysql, row

This is not the first time I have used `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` to get a specific column of a row. For some reason I can not figure out why it is not working this time around. Heres my code:

```
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE PushNumber > 0";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        // This will loop through each row, now use your loop here
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $pushNumber = $row['PushNumber'];
        $followingIDs = $row['FollowingIDs'];
        $usernameID = $row['Username'];
        error_log("'$pushNumber", 0);
        error_log("'$usernameID", 0);
    }
}
```

There is one row in my table where `PushNumber` is greater than `0` and `$pushNumber` (type: `int`) and `$usernameID` (type: `string`) are printed in the error log and both are printed as: `''` *AND I DON'T KNOW WHY!* There are no spelling errors and I know for a fact in that row `PushNumber` is equal to `1` and `Username` is equal to `@yo`. Any suggestions would be appreciated please help. Thank you!

Comment: not enough info to get any proper conclusion; however, this may help: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Check for errors on the execution.

Comment: Why don't you post your exact code. This is not valid code. For example error_log("'$pushNumber", 0); will poduce a syntax error

Comment: it is exact code and it throws no such error on my side?

Comment: You `mysqli_fetch_array()` in your loop and then immediately `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.  So you fetch one row and then overwrite `$row` fetching another.  So you only get the even rows.  In the case of one row you get none assigned to `row`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to assign two completely different sets of values into your $row variable.

`$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)` transfers the entire array into $row, but then in your loop you use `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` to transfer a single record into $row, which is most likely throwing your loop off.

Try this:

```
if($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        // This will loop through each row, now capture each row's data here
        $pushNumber = $row['PushNumber'];
        $followingIDs = $row['FollowingIDs'];
        $usernameID = $row['Username'];
        error_log($pushNumber, 0);
        error_log($usernameID, 0);
    }
}
```